# Why erase+remove is more efficient than remove

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, stl

I'm coding C++ to solve this problem from Leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-element/

> Given an array nums and a value val, remove all instances of that
>   value in-place and return the new length.
>
> Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by
>   modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.
>
> The order of elements can be changed. It doesn't matter what you leave
>   beyond the new length.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Given nums = [3,2,2,3], val = 3,
>
> Your function should return length = 2, with the first two elements of
>   nums being 2.
>
> It doesn't matter what you leave beyond the returned length.

I have two solutions:

Solution A:

```
int removeElement(vector<int>& nums, int val) {
    nums.erase(remove(begin(nums), end(nums), val), end(nums));
    return nums.size();
}
```

Solution B:

```
int removeElement(vector<int>& nums, int val) {
    auto it = std::remove(nums.begin(), nums.end(), val);
    return it - nums.begin();
}
```

In my opinion, Solution B should be faster than Solution A. However, the result is the opposite:

Solution A spent 0 ms, whereas Solution B spent 4 ms.

I don't know why `remove + erase` is faster than `remove`.

Comment: What *is* `nums`? Are its iterators random access? If not then `it - nums.begin()` has to manually step through all iterators to get the difference.

Comment: Also note that the two snippets of code does very different things.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  sorry, reedited.

Comment: @Jarod42   I've added more information.

Comment: Now the issue becomes how you measure, what the data in the vector is, how you build the program. And about the two snippets not doing the same thing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  It is not me who measures. Leetcode measures.

Comment: Then the difference is probably because of the different behavior from the two functions.

Comment: 0ms and 4ms are small enough values that any difference is mostly meaningless. They could be easily affected by things like other processes running on the machine.

Comment: "It is not me who measures. Leetcode measures." dont trust any measurments that you didnt mess up yourself. Measuring code can be tricky and details do matter. What are the compiler options? What is the surrounding code? What clock was used to measure? These factors can turn the results into the opposite and only stating 4ms / 0ms is rather meaningless. Never used it myself, but you can try here: http://quick-bench.com/

Comment: It's possible that compiler knows erase–remove idiom and can optimize it better. Also, for `std::vector` erasing `n` last elements is a single arithmetic operation (for primitive types).

Comment: http://quick-bench.com/cEHVU6KHeWUNkaIbocUj3iyxtgc

Comment: @GauravSehgal: Not really relevant with only empty vector.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen or anything with a trivial destructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a vector of trivially destructible type (`int` is one such type), `erase(it, end())` is usually just a decrement of a size member (or pointer member, depending on the implementation strategy) that takes almost no time.  4 milliseconds is a very very small difference.  It can be easily caused by the state of the machine.  And I won't expect such a small difference will be reproducible.

If you want to really remove the elements from the vector, go with the first version.  If you really want to do what `std::remove` does (you probably don't), go with the second version.  Performance is not the problem here.

Comment: Also, for the second version the argument would be better as a `std::span<int>`.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yeah, that would be better.

Comment: Actually, for vector, `erase(it, end())` requires both a decrement of an integral (size, pointer, whatever) member variable _and_ the call to a destructor. For `int`s, the destructor does nothing (or doesn't exist; your choice) and generates no code.

Comment: @MarshallClow Yeah, it's trivial.  Updated.